# Jshint.com | Assigning to 'this' 

Tags: javascript, jshint

In jshint.com whenever I do

```
var this_hold = this;
```

I get an error.

I get a violation of strict error.

The application is such that I need to work with either this ( passed in from an event handler) or I need to pull the element myself using `document.getElementById()`

It's just how this function works best...otherwise I have to write it twice once for each case.

I want the error gone..I don't want to turn it off.  I want jshint.com 100% happy.

Here is the function in question with the violation commented

```
/**
 *vFlipBP - eliminate select_element in favor of 'this'
 */

function vFlipBP( element_or_string ) {
    var previous_page_element,
        previous_tag_element,
        current_page_element,
        select_element;
    console.log( 'element_or_string ' + element_or_string ); 
    if( typeof ( element_or_string ) === 'string' ) {
        select_element = document.getElementById( element_or_string );
    } else {
        select_element = this;  // violation of strict here
    }
    if( vFlipBP.previous_id === undefined ) {
        var probe_id = select_element.parentElement.firstChild.id;
        if ( ( probe_id === select_element.id ) && ( select_element.parentElement.firstChild.nextSibling ) ) {
            probe_id = select_element.parentElement.firstChild.nextSibling.id;
            vFlipBP.previous_id = probe_id;
        } else {
            vFlipBP.previous_id = select_element.id;
        }
    }
    current_page_element = document.getElementById( select_element.id + '_page' );
    current_page_element.style.display = '';
    select_element.style.background = "#eeeeee";
    if( vFlipBP.previous_id !== select_element.id ) {
        previous_page_element = document.getElementById( vFlipBP.previous_id + '_page' );
        previous_tag_element = document.getElementById( vFlipBP.previous_id );
        if( ( ( previous_page_element !== current_page_element ) ) && ( previous_page_element !== null ) ) {
            previous_page_element.style.display = 'none';
            previous_tag_element.style.background = "#ffffff";
        }
    }
    vFlipBP.previous_id = select_element.id;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an option `validthis` to turn off that warning. Unfortunately, you can't detect all strict mode violations just by doing static analysis so JSHint makes a guess—and sometimes it is wrong.

More about `validthis` and other options in our docs: http://www.jshint.com/docs/

Comment: There is no need to be proud of not using options. JSHint is not there to tell you how to code—it is there to help you spot potential problems. And since static analysis can get you only so far we will always have false positives.

Comment: Well...I finally did it anyways...not options set...no errors...there were multiple fixes actually...see post here....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961735/jshint-passing-default-settings-function-declarations-and-this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign to `this`; it's read-only.

However, assigning the value of `this` to another variable is *not* erroneous, and it does not violate "use stict" rules.

Comment: Line 15: select_element = this;

Possible strict violation.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist is that from JSLint or something?  If so, JSLint is really dumb; it makes goofball errors like that a lot.  Basically it's not keeping track of the fact that the variable was correctly declared with `var`.

Comment: Unfortunately those analysis tools have very weak parsers. That's why it says "**Possible** strict violation."

Comment: Hey JSHint maintainer(s) sorry about the "weak" comment :-)