# Jshint | Passing default settings | Function declarations and 'this'

Tags: javascript, jshint

```
for ( element = 0; element < this.tag_array.length; element++ ) {
    document.getElementById( this.tag_array[element] ).addEventListener(
    "click", function(){ /* constructor function here */ } );  // jshint.com error #1
}
```

This code will cause an error in jshint.com b.c. it does not want to see functions declared in a loop.

However, if I pass in a simple function reference then I can not extract out 'this' with out once again breaking jshint.

```
for ( element = 0; element < this.tag_array.length; element++ ) {
    document.getElementById( this.tag_array[element] ).addEventListener(
    "click", vFlipBP );
}
```

Now I've when I use 'this' in vFlipBP, I get an error b.c. it expects 'this' to be used in conjunction with a constructor function.

```
function vFlipBP(){ var foo = this ; } // jshint error #2
```

Because of this, I find it impossible to make jsthint.com happy in this particular function.

Nevermind turning off the jshint.com options.

Is it possible to write code that passes jshint.com default settings.

I'm just trying to understand the reasoning behind why it makes these warnings/errors.

I'm not hung up on worrying about the error ( it is optional I could just turn it off )...I just want to know if it is possible to pass the default...is there an angle I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't seem concerned about making several identical functions, it seems that JSHint doesn't mind this...

```
var element;
for ( element = 0; element < 10; element++ ) {
    document.getElementById( this.tag_array[element] ).addEventListener(
    "click", make_func() );
}

function make_func() {
  "use strict";
  return function(){ var foo = this; alert(foo); };
}
```

---

It also seems accepting if you don't use the function declaration syntax...

```
var element;
var the_func = function(){ 
  "use strict";
  var foo = this; 
  alert(foo); 
};


for ( element = 0; element < 10; element++ ) {
    document.getElementById( this.tag_array[element] ).addEventListener(
    "click", the_func );
}
```

Comment: @HiroProtagonist: You get errors in your own code using these techniques?

Comment: you are not using a constructor function with this...yet you get no error.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist: I can only assume that it sees its use as an event handler, and knows the `this` value will be set when the event occurs. Not sure why it would make a difference in your code. I had to modify the code a bit since a full example wasn't posted, so maybe there's some difference there.

Comment: I used your first example...no idea why it works...but it does!...I guess Trial and Error is key....Thanks again

Comment: snap!...your first example works in that it passes jslint...but the function does not fire on the event...it does not fire.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you'd like to use `this` as the context in the callback but jshint complains about using this in a function that is not a constructor.

So suppose this is the code you had

```
function showId() {
   alert(this.id); // jshint warning here
}
for ( element = 0; element < this.tag_array.length; element++ ) {
    document.getElementById( this.tag_array[element] ).addEventListener(
    "click", showId ); 
}
```

You'd have to rewrite your function so it doesn't use `this`, here's a possible way

```
function createHandler(obj) {
    return function(e) {
        alert(obj.id);
    }
}

for ( element = 0; element < this.tag_array.length; element++ ) {
    var nodeId = this.tag_array[element];
    var node =  document.getElementById(nodeId);
    node.addEventListener("click", createHandler(node)); 
}
```

Can't you tell jshint that this specific function is safe to use `this`? With the `validthis` this option? In Google Closure Compiler you can do so by using the  `@this` to specify that you know what `this` will be in that function (and avoid the warning) https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler

Comment: @HiroProtagonist Not sure what you mean with "must me a function constructor" Show your actual code in the function inside the loop

Comment: to use 'this' and pass default setting on jshint....this must only be used in a function constructor like this.....var function_constructor = function(){ // code here };

Comment: @HiroProtagonist See my example, you don't have to use `this` in your function, you use me, which is a closure variable pointing to the original `this`

Comment: @HiroProtagonist I think I see what you mean, you want to use the context that the function is called in, in this case the node itself as `this`?

Comment: @HiroProtagonist It's not similar, "am not i am" is still using the keyword `this`, I'm avoiding it by passing the node into the callback function creator

Comment: Is this valid, I thought addEventListener only takes a function reference -  node.addEventListener("click", createHandler(node));

Comment: @HiroProtagonist `createHandler` returns a function, so yeah, it's valid. This is a common pattern when you want to use the same function, but you'd like to create an extra closure, in our case, we're using it to pass the extra argument, since we don't want to use `this`

Comment: O.K...this is giving my feeble mind a head-ache...need some time to let is soak in.

Comment: I ended up using am not i am's first method b.c. it was the easiest..have no idea why it works or if it's good practice...but need a break...thanks again.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist Here's a link that should help you understand the concept. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind `Function.bind` is a function that returns another function that is bound to a specific context (`this`) and a set of arguments. Don't  let your mind stay feeble :) , this is an important concept in JavaScript. I don't understand how amnotiam's method avoids the warning, but whatever solution you use for this, you should still understand the concept of returning functions from functions, it's really powerful.